# Black patches in bump texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders

[image]

How do I get rid of these black patches? I want a clean render.

[image]

Material Node Setup
[image]

Answer (score 1):

higher bump values tend to give those black values. reduce the bump intensity and see if it works

Comment: Any suggestions to keep that bump look preserved and reduce values?

Comment: reduce the value in very small amount. if this doesn't work, i think I would try displacing the plane with a displace modifier... that might slow down the renders though...